# How to create an interactive plot of GTFS data in R using Leaflet?

Tags: r, dictionary, gis, leaflet, gtfs

I would like to create an interactive map showing the public transport lines of a city. I am trying to do this using Leaflet in R (but I'm open to alternatives, suggestions?)

Data: The data of the transport system is in GTFS format, organized in text files (.txt), which I read into R as a data frame.*

The Problem: I cannot find how to indicate the id of each Poly line (variable shape_id) so the plot would actually follow the route of each transit line. Instead, it is connecting the dots in a random sequence.

Here is what I've tried, so far without success:

```
# Download GTFS data of the Victoria Regional Transit System
  tf <- tempfile() 
  td <- tempdir()
  ftp.path <- "http://www.gtfs-data-exchange.com/agency/bc-transit-victoria-regional-transit-system/latest.zip"
  download.file(ftp.path, tf) 

# Read text file to a data frame
  zipfile <- unzip( tf , exdir = td )
  shape <- read.csv(zipfile[9])

# Create base map
  basemap <- leaflet() %>% addTiles()


# Add transit layer
  basemap  %>% addPolylines(lng=shape$shape_pt_lon, lat=shape$shape_pt_lat, 
                            fill = FALSE,
                            layerId =shape$shape_id)
```

I would be glad to have your comments on this.

*I know it is possible to import this data into a GIS software (e.g. QGIS) to create a shapefile and then read the shapefile into R with readOGR. [Robin Lovelace has shown how to do this](http://www.r-bloggers.com/the-leaflet-package-for-online-mapping-in-r/). BUT, I am looking for a pure R solution. ;)

ps. [Kyle Walker has written a great intro to interactive maps in R using Leaflet](http://rpubs.com/walkerke/rstudio_gis). Unfortunately, he doesn't cover poly lines in his tutorial.

Comment: You could try picking out only the longest shape for each route so that you don't have duplicate shapes for each route - that will make the data you need to plot a lot smaller See my talk on exactly that (Page 27) https://drive.google.com/file/d/191Jq1awInmtXPXrVlywXXaQjxv0basHe/
(also on YouTube)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is not one of method but of data: note that you download 8 MB and that the line file you try to load into Leaflet via shiny is 5 MB. As a general principle, you should always try new methods with tiny datasets first, before scaling them up. This is what I do below to diagnose the problem and solve it.

## Stage 1: Explore and subset the data

```
pkgs <- c("leaflet", "shiny" # packages we'll use
  , "maps" # to test antiquated 'maps' data type
  , "maptools" # to convert 'maps' data type to Spatial* data
  )
lapply(pkgs, "library", character.only = TRUE)


class(shape)
## [1] "data.frame"

head(shape)

##   shape_id shape_pt_lon shape_pt_lat shape_pt_sequence
## 1 1-39-220    -123.4194     48.49065                 0
## 2 1-39-220    -123.4195     48.49083                 1
## 3 1-39-220    -123.4195     48.49088                 2
## 4 1-39-220    -123.4196     48.49123                 3
## 5 1-39-220    -123.4197     48.49160                 4
## 6 1-39-220    -123.4196     48.49209                 5

object.size(shape) / 1000000 # 5 MB!!!

## 5.538232 bytes

summary(shape$shape_id)
shape$shape_id <- as.character(shape$shape_id)
ids <- unique(shape$shape_id)
shape_orig <- shape
shape <- shape[shape$shape_id == ids[1],] # subset the data
```

## Stage 2: Convert to a Spatial* object

Is this like the `data.frame` objects from maps?

```
state.map <- map("state", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE)
str(state.map)

## List of 4
##  $ x    : num [1:15599] -87.5 -87.5 -87.5 -87.5 -87.6 ...
##  $ y    : num [1:15599] 30.4 30.4 30.4 30.3 30.3 ...
##  $ range: num [1:4] -124.7 -67 25.1 49.4
##  $ names: chr [1:63] "alabama" "arizona" "arkansas" "california" ...
##  - attr(*, "class")= chr "map"
```

*Yes*, it's similar, so we can use `map2Spatial*` to convert it:

```
shape_map <- list(x = shape$shape_pt_lon, y = shape$shape_pt_lat)
shape_lines <- map2SpatialLines(shape_map, IDs = ids[1])
plot(shape_lines) # success - this plots a single line!
```

[image: line]

## Stage 3: Join all the lines together

A `for` loop will do this nicely. Note we only use the first 10 lines. Use `2:length(ids)` for all lines:

```
for(i in 2:10){
  shape <- shape_orig[shape_orig$shape_id == ids[i],]
  shape_map <- list(x = shape$shape_pt_lon, y = shape$shape_pt_lat)
  shape_temp <- map2SpatialLines(shape_map, IDs = ids[i])
  shape_lines <- spRbind(shape_lines, shape_temp)
}
```

## Stage 4: Plot

Using the `SpatialLines` object makes the code a little shorter - this will plot the first 10 lines in this case:

```
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolylines(data = shape_lines)
```

[image: first-10]

## Conclusion

You needed to play around with the data and manipulate it before converting it into a Spatial* data type for plotting, with the correct IDs. `maptools::map2Spatial*`, `unique()` and a clever `for` loop can solve the problem.

Comment: It works great Robin. Thank you. I was thinking about the 'data problem' you mentioned, though. Because, in the end, when I apply your solution to map all transit routes, your code also loads into Leaflet an object of 5 MB (shape_lines).

Comment: True that, but for the purposes of testing and reproducibility, problems should be reduced to their smallest/simplest form

Comment: maptools now deprecated: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/maptools/versions/1.1-8